# Regex is returning all matches in one group

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm having an problem to return the matches in separated groups, since the last match ")" only works in the last register.
I want to return all three matches in the example below.
Any advice?

Link to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IXJR29/1).

```py
regex = "\[\]\(((?s).*)\)"


text = " ![](https://tomticket-
         anexos.s3.amazonaws.com/inimg/imagename1.jpg)

         ![](https://tomticket-
         anexos.s3.amazonaws.com/inimg/imagename2.jpg)

         ![](https://tomticket-
         anexos.s3.amazonaws.com/inimg/imagename2.jpg)
       "
```

everything after the first ![](  and last ) is returned.

Comment: It might help if you mention which language you are using. Or add an appropriate language tag (just the language you're using, please).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `.*` is greedy. It will consume as much characters as it can, including any closed parentheses it may find along the way.

To fix this problem, use `[^)]*` to tell regex that you are explicitly excluding the `)` character from the list of characters that you want to capture.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/wB860p/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `\[\]\(((?s).*)\)` will first match `[](` and then uses an inline modifier `(?s)` which will make the dot match a newline so `.*` will match till the end and will then backtrack until the last `)`

You could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) instead matching from the opening parenthesis `(` until the first closing parenthesis `)`.

```
!\[\]\([^)]+\)
```

- `!` Match literally if you also want to match that
- `\[\]` Match `[]`
- `\(` Match `(`
- `[^)]+` Match 1+ times any char except `)` which will also match a newline
- `\)` Match `)`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i36ztR/1)